# Refresh DataGrid in silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` with columns inside it.

I want the `DataGrid` to be **refreshed every 3 seconds**, with data from the service.

I need that the `Scroll` will not jump to the top of the `DataGrid`, every time it refreshes, and stay on the same place of the `Scroll`. Is it possible?

Here is my code :

```
<sdk:DataGrid  Grid.Row="1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="RealTimeReportDataGrid" 
      RowEditEnded="LinesDataGrid_RowEditEnded" RowHeight="40">
      <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>...</sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

This is the code behind:

```
        public RealTimeReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnViewLoaded;
        RealTimeReportService.RealTimeReportServiceClient RTws = new RealTimeReportService.RealTimeReportServiceClient();
        RTws.GetRealTimeReportAsync();
        RTws.GetRealTimeReportCompleted += new EventHandler<RealTimeReportService.GetRealTimeReportCompletedEventArgs>(RTws_GetRealTimeReportCompleted);

    }

    void RTws_GetRealTimeReportCompleted(object sender, RealTimeReportService.GetRealTimeReportCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.Result.ToList();
        RealTimeReportDataGrid.ItemsSource = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ShahalDialerRT.RealTimeReportService.RealTimeReport>(e.Result.ToList());
    }


    private void OnViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Start();
    }

    private void OnUpdaterTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RealTimeReportService.RealTimeReportServiceClient RTws = new RealTimeReportService.RealTimeReportServiceClient();
        RTws.GetRealTimeReportAsync();
        RTws.GetRealTimeReportCompleted += new EventHandler<RealTimeReportService.GetRealTimeReportCompletedEventArgs>(RTws_GetRealTimeReportCompleted);
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        InitializeRefreshDataTimer();
    }


    public void InitializeRefreshDataTimer()
    {
        _updaterTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 3000);
        _updaterTimer.Tick += OnUpdaterTimerTick;
        _updaterTimer.Start();
    }
```

Thanks ahead.

**Update:**
@StepUp, this is the only change I made, according to what you said, but still no change :(

```
void RTws_GetRealTimeReportCompleted(object sender, RealTimeReportService.GetRealTimeReportCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = e.Result.ToList();

    RealTimeReportDataGrid.ItemsSource = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ShahalDialerRT.RealTimeReportService.RealTimeReport>(e.Result.ToList());

    this.RealTimeReportDataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        RealTimeReportDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(
        RealTimeReportDataGrid.SelectedItem,
        RealTimeReportDataGrid.CurrentColumn);
    });
    //RealTimeReportDataGrid.ItemsSource = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ShahalDialerRT.RealTimeReportService.RealTimeReport>(e.Result.ToList());
    //RealTimeReportDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
    //RealTimeReportDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(RealTimeReportDataGrid.SelectedItem, RealTimeReportDataGrid.Columns[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refresh every 3 seconds just [use `Timer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Interval=3000;
aTimer.Enabled=true;


// Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     //add new data
}
```

The `Elapsed` event will be raised every X amount of seconds, specified in milliseconds by the `Interval` property on the Timer object. It will call the `Event Handler` method you specify, in the example above it is `OnTimedEvent`.

To stay `Scroll` on the same position in `DataGrid`:

```
yourDataGrid.ItemsSource = data; 
yourDataGrid.UpdateLayout(); 
yourDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(theDataGrid.SelectedItem, theDataGrid.Columns[0]);
```

**Update:**

```
yourDataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    yourDataGrid.Focus();      
    yourDataGrid.SelectedItem=whateverYouWant;
    yourDataGrid.CurrentColumn=yourDataGrid.Columns[0];
    yourDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(yourDataGrid.SelectedItem, yourDataGrid.CurrentColumn);
});
```

OR:

```
yourDataGrid.SelectedIndex = 5; // the index you want to select
yourDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
yourDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(Grid.SelectedItem, 0);
```

Comment: I edited my original post, just in same time you have answerd. Now the refreshing is ok, but the scroling is still jumping to the top after I scroll down.

Comment: @David have you seen the bottom part of my answer? Have you tried `yourDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(theDataGrid.SelectedItem, theDataGrid.Columns[0]);`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to place it in the end of 'RTws_GetRealTimeReportCompleted'. But nothing changed.

Comment: Thanks, it is helped me!